# How to run a script when user logs in?

Tags: login, scripts

I want to register hour and date of users in a network after they login, so, to do it, I want to run a script after every login, and it will create a file contain login hour and date.

The problem is: I don't know how to configure pam_script to run this script after every login.
I have to add commands in common-auth file? I'm not certainly.

help, pelase!

Comment: Are you running a graphical DE ? Do you "need" to use pam ? If so see http://blog.stalkr.net/2010/11/login-notifications-pamexec-scripting.html and if it is not working post your configuration files, what you edited, and your script.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't saw your help before, thanks. I'll try it and I'll let comments here soon.

Comment: thank you bodhi.zazen. I'm using pam_exec, its running scripts on login and logout, but I have to catch IP, username, date and if he's in login or logout. Do you know these variables, in special the last, login/logout?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command "last" which tells you about the log in time of all users. It might be helpful for your scenario , you can know more about it by reading its man page.

Comment: Thanks for answer Vihann. Well, I need register in a file in a folder, when users log in. pam_script is installed but I can't configure it to run my script.
Wich editings I have to do to pam_script run my script?